# Multiple Rows for same identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a query that I don't have to use GROUP BY to get my items in else they'll split data into rows. Here is what I have, which runs, but I am getting multiple rows for the same `patient_id` and the `last_service` and `last_payment` never appear in the same row. I'm getting 3 rows where they seem to split by `last_service`, `last_payment`, and a row where both are NULL. Here is my query:

```
WITH adj_rep_les AS(
SELECT DISTINCT t.clinic, t.patient_id, a.adj_desc
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN adjustments a
    ON(t.clinic=a.clinic AND a.adjustment_id=t.adjustment_id)
WHERE a.adj_desc LIKE '%TAB%'
AND time_ran > '2016-03-27')

SELECT DISTINCT
        c.clinic_id,
        w.patient_id,
        p.city,
        p.state,
        p.zipcode,
        SUM(t.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY w.clinic, w.patient_id) AS balance,
        CASE WHEN t.impacts='P' THEN FIRST_VALUE(t.date_entered) OVER (PARTITION BY w.clinic, w.patient_id ORDER BY t.date_entered DESC) END AS last_service,
        CASE WHEN t.impacts='C' THEN FIRST_VALUE(t.date_entered) OVER (PARTITION BY w.clinic, w.patient_id ORDER BY t.date_entered DESC) END AS last_payment,
        FIRST_VALUE(s.description) OVER (PARTITION BY w.clinic, w.patient_id ORDER BY t.date_entered DESC) AS service_done

FROM adj_rep_les w
LEFT JOIN clinic_master c
    ON (w.clinic=c.clinic)
LEFT JOIN patient p
    ON (w.clinic=p.clinic AND w.patient_id=p.patient_id)
LEFT JOIN transactions t
    ON (w.clinic=t.clinic AND w.patient_id=t.patient_id)
LEFT JOIN services s
    ON (t.clinic=s.clinic AND t.service_code=s.service_code)
```

Any thoughts? I would also mention that the `FIRST_VALUE` within the `CASE` don't seem to be working and giving the same result regardless as if ignoring the filter for `t.impacts`. Alternatively tried using MAX(t.date_entered) within the case but that requires a `GROUP BY` due to `MAX` being an aggregated function

Sample Data Results:
[image: Sample Data]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, as no sample data and ddl provided. Try move         `CASE WHEN t.impacts='P' THEN FIRST_VALUE(t.date_entered) OVER (PARTITION BY w.clinic, w.patient_id ORDER BY t.date_entered DESC) END AS last_service,
        CASE WHEN t.impacts='C' THEN FIRST_VALUE(t.date_entered) OVER (PARTITION BY w.clinic, w.patient_id ORDER BY t.date_entered DESC) END AS last_payment,` to CTE and pivot them in CTE, and drop join with transaction in main SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the issues are:

- The join with `transactions` results in a record per transaction, while you would only want one record per patient. To solve this you could perform the selection of transactions in a sub query and filter one record per patient from it;
- The `CASE` constructs defeat the logic where you want one record per patient, as you can never have both conditions true at the same time. Instead these `CASE` constructs should appear within some aggregation.

Less of a problem:

- You use `LEFT JOIN` in places where it is clear that an `INNER JOIN` would have the same results. The latter has generally better performance, so I would suggest to use it where possible.
- You don't use `adj_desc` outside of the CTE, so there is no need to `SELECT` it;
- You don't use the `master_clinic` table for anything else than the primary key value, which you already have, so I think you can leave that table out;
- You use the column `clinic` for referential integrity, but select `clinic_id`. I assume this is a typo.

Here is the query I would suggest:

```
WITH adj_rep_les AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.clinic, t.patient_id
    FROM       transactions t
    INNER JOIN adjustments a
           ON  t.clinic=a.clinic 
           AND a.adjustment_id=t.adjustment_id
    WHERE      a.adj_desc LIKE '%TAB%'
    AND        time_ran > '2016-03-27')
SELECT DISTINCT
            w.clinic,
            w.patient_id,
            p.city,
            p.state,
            p.zipcode,
            x.balance,
            x.last_service,
            x.last_payment,
            x.service_done
FROM        adj_rep_les w
INNER JOIN  patient p
        ON  w.clinic=p.clinic
        AND w.patient_id=p.patient_id
INNER JOIN  (
            SELECT     t.clinic,
                       t.patient_id,
                       SUM(t.amount)
                           OVER (PARTITION BY t.clinic, t.patient_id) AS balance,
                       MAX(CASE WHEN t.impacts='P' THEN t.date_entered END) 
                           OVER (PARTITION BY t.clinic, t.patient_id) AS last_service,
                       MAX(CASE WHEN t.impacts='C' THEN t.date_entered END) 
                           OVER (PARTITION BY t.clinic, t.patient_id) AS last_payment,
                       ROW_NUMBER() 
                           OVER (PARTITION BY t.clinic, t.patient_id 
                               ORDER BY t.date_entered DESC) AS rn,
                       s.description AS service_done
            FROM       transactions t
            LEFT JOIN  services s
                   ON  t.clinic=s.clinic
                   AND t.service_code=s.service_code) as x
        ON  w.clinic=x.clinic
        AND w.patient_id=x.patient_id
        AND rn = 1
```

The `rn = 1` condition makes sure you get exactly one record from the `transaction` table, the one with the most recent `date_entered` for a given patient and clinic.

Comment: @OM Asphyxiate, did this solve your issue? Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: This did indeed seem to work as I was hoping. I'm still fairly new to SQL and have been making due with what I've learned so far. I appreciate all the help and insight into the matter.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to post new questions!